# x11-forwarding a window to another computer

Tags: x11, multi-monitor

So I have set up X11 forwarding between two computers such that I can open a gui program in the server (in terminal) and it starts in the client. I followed the variant A in this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/207189/794249

Now I would like to know if there is a way to forward a single window in a multi-window program running in server to the client (for instance, in gimp floating mode).

What I am exactly trying to accomplish here is a sort of dual monitor effect where a laggy client laptop can be a sort of preview monitor (which does not need to be realtime). Used in conjunction with mouse sharing program, I imagine it might work.

I don't know much about the internals of X and things like that so if you think that this approach is not suitable for what I am trying to accomplish, then any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Not easily: The client (gimp) opens a connection to a specific X server using the `DISPLAY` variable/options, and then asks the X server to open windows etc. Which means all windows will "belong" to the same X server, you can't just switch a window between different X servers (one local, one remote). To make a client use several X servers at once, that has to be baked into the client.

I'm not sure about your exact use case (Do you want to use the laptop as a laggy second screen in a "multi-screen" setup on your main computer? Do you want to graphically access applications on different computer on an application-by-application basis? Something different?), but have a look at [Xpra](https://xpra.org) to see if that could do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

There exist programs that can do what you propose, [xbattle](https://github.com/mikemayer67/xbattle) is one example, source should be available. but it is written from the start to be multi-headed.  Trying to retrofit that onto an existing application could be tricky.

Comment: Could you link to the project xbattle?

Comment: I downloaded it off usenet (possibly alt.sources) in 1991, we had black and white displays (one bit per pixel) in the undergrad lab